# Logcat shows log messages but application filter does not work in-app

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I've been struggling with a logcat bug for some time now. I can see log messages of all the other apps, services, libraries, etc. on my Android phone but I'm not able to filter it to only my application as I could before in Android Studio.

If I select my package name in the drop down and then pair that with `Show only selected application`, the logcat is empty. If I instead use a saved filter that filters by "LOGTAG" (which is my logtag), it shows me a few log messages that are hours old.

However, if I use the command line and pipe the output: `adb logcat | find "LOGTAG"` I am able to see my log messages real-time as expected.

I have tried restarting Android Studio, re-installing, restarting adb server, and seating the USB wire properly.

Comment: Are you using a release build variant by chance? If so, that could explain it.Also, did you verify in app build.gradle file that you didn;t turn off debugging?

Comment: @Jarvis I'm using a debug build variant and I don't see anything in build.gradle that would imply I've turned off debugging. It's very strange because just now some of the more recent log messages were updated (<10 minutes old), almost like Android Studio was catching up on a backlog